# LISP modify list passed as argument

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

So i got this function that receives a list as an argument

```
(defun do-transf (lst)
```

...

my initial lst is ((NIL NIL) (NIL NIL))
but in the end i want the lst becomes

(NIL NIL NIL NIL)

example

> `(defvar a (list (list NIL NIL) (list NIL NIL)))`
>
> `(do-transf a)`

`(NIL NIL NIL NIL)`  -> gives the right answer but when i call the list this isnt the answer

> a

((NIL NIL) (NIL NIL)) -> i dont want this

Comment: I understand that you want this to be destructive (from the comments on one of the answers), but how exactly?  In the first case, `a` is  list of two elements (each of which is equal to `(nil nil)`, but let's call them `x` and `y` for the moment).  So `a` is `(x . (y . nil))`, i.e., a list made of two cons cells, let's call them `xc` and `yc`. The result that you want is `(n1 . (n2 . (n3 . (n4 . nil))))` (`n` stands for `nil`), which is a list made of four cons cells.  `xc` and `yc` could be reused, but where are the other two going to come from?

Answer (score 2):

Your post suggests that you wish to do **list concatenation**, i.e. append lists to another.

As such, try this:

```
(defvar a (list (list NIL NIL) (list NIL NIL)))
(apply #'append a)
```

This outputs:

```
(NIL NIL NIL NIL)
```

Short, simple, sweet.

UPDATE:

Since you want **destructive** behavior (that is, modification of the original value of `a`):

```
(setq a (apply #'append a))
```

Now, `a` is set to this new value (from `((NIL NIL) (NIL NIL))`):

```
(NIL NIL NIL NIL)
```

Comment: @user2967111: You want **destructive** behavior? That is, you wish to modify `a`?

Comment: @user2967111: That behavior is **correct**. Very few LISP functions *ever* require you to modify the value of something. The LISP-way of doing things is to operate on the data you entered, then *return* the modified data.

Comment: (defun bla (lst) (setq lst (apply #'append a)))

(defvar a (list (list NIL NIL) (list NIL NIL))

(bla a)

(NIL NIL NIL NIL)

a

((NIL NIL) (NIL NIL))

the list remains the same..

Comment: sorry for that representation but i cant answer my on question yet

Comment: @user2967111: There are a lot of problems with what you just wrote. **A lot**. Please don't take this the wrong way, but I think you should look at a good LISP source to better your understanding of the language in tandem with learning it. Wishing you well.

Comment: let me comment this slowlly

Comment: (defun bla (lst) (setq lst (apply #'append lst)))

Comment: (defvar a (list (list NIL NIL) (list NIL NIL)))

Comment: (bla a) outputs: (NIL NIL NIL NIL)

Comment: a outputs: ((NIL NIL) (NIL NIL))

Comment: @user2967111: Not surprisingly. You aren't setting `a` to the value returned by `bla`. Your function should be: `(defun bla () (setq a (apply #'append a)))`. As for if this is good LISP programming, that's another story...

Comment: dude a is the list passed as argument

Comment: @user2967111: I know that, but there are a lot of deeper issues here. ... *I'm sorry buddy, but you're on your own now.* We are having serious communication problems as **your understanding of the language is *severely* lacking** and I can only explain so much. **I wish you well in arriving at the conclusion you wanted.** :)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, lisp functions don't mutate the data they operate on. This is not a required property, but it does make it much easier writing and reasoning about large code bases.

So, what typically happens is that a function will return a copy of the new data, that can then replace the old value in a variable, at the discretion of the caller.

Even when functions destructively modify data structures, they tend to return the new resulting value.

If we look at the following code:

```
(defvar *example* '(delete 2 3 4))
=> *example*
(delete 'delete *example*)
=> (2 3 4)
*example*
=> (delete 2 3 4)
```

This is because there is *no* way for the function to destructively modify `*example*` so it loses the first element, so even when you are using destructive, mutating functions, they need to return a value suitable for storing back into the variable that the input came from.

Answer (score 0):

Try using flatten..

```
(defvar a (flatten (list (list NIL NIL) (list NIL NIL))))
```

Comment: thats not the point, i know how to go from ((NIL NIL) (NIL NIL)) 
to (NIL NIL NIL NIL) 
what i want is that the list becomes that